# Pattern to subclass logging.Logger

Tags: python, logging, subclass

Is there a common pattern to follow to correctly subclass `logging.Logger`?

```
import logging

class MyLogger(logging.Logger):
    __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__(name=name)
```

Does not seem to work property, as `MyLogger` created this way has no reference to its parent. Although I could manually set its parent, but am afraid that maybe there are other protocols of `loggging.Logger` not satisfied as well by `MyLogger`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How are you creating your logger instance? The canonical way to do it is to never directly instantiate a Logger and instead use the Manager. The logging lib has `setLoggerClass` to tell the manager which class to use when creating Loggers. The manager also sets up parents:

```
import logging

class MyLogger(logging.Logger):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__(name=name)

logging.setLoggerClass(MyLogger)

logger = logging.getLogger('some_logger')
child_logger = logging.getLogger('some_logger.child')

print(type(logger)) # MyLogger
print(logger.parent) # shows the root logger
print(child_logger.parent) # shows 'some_logger'
```

Comment: What if you need to pass some arguments to the custom logger sub-class? setLoggerClass does not allow it. What would be the right design then?

Comment: @LucaM if you have a specific use-case than best to ask a question, but 90% of custom logger classes I have seen so far shouldn't even exist. Most of the time what you actually want is either a custom Handler, logging Adapter or custom Formatter.