# Pattern to subclass logging.Logger with extra arguments

Tags: python, logging

Following the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66540452/pattern-to-subclass-logging-logger), how would I approach the design if I have a custom `extra` argument to pass to the custom class constructor?

```
class CustomLogger(logging.Logger):   
    def __init__(
        self,
        name: str,
        level: int = logging.NOTSET,
        extra: dict = None,
    ) -> None:
        # the logger class level depends on the "debug_mode" of extra
        # if True, the logging.DEBUG is used
        # else, the logging.INFO is used
        self._extra= extra
        debug_mode = self._extra.get("debug_mode", False)
        level = logging.DEBUG if debug_mode else logging.INFO
        super().__init__(name, level)

        # the logger class verbosity depends on the "verbose" from logging configuration
        self.verbose = cfg.get("verbose", False)

        # the logger class datetime format depends on the "datetime_format" from logging configuration
        datefmt = cfg.get("datetime_format", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

        # save custom formatters for file and console handlers
        # NOTE: the console formatter subclasses the file formatter and add colored logs
        self._file_formatter = CustomFileFormatter(verbose=self.verbose, datefmt=datefmt)
        self._console_formatter = CustomConsoleFormatter()

        # NOTE: logging to file feature is enabled if the configuration is found
        self._fileinfo = cfg.get("file", None)

        # Add custom log levels
        self._addCustomLevels()

        # Set up the custom console formatter
        self._setConsoleHandler()

        # Set up SMTP handler for emails, if required
        self._setCustomSMTPHandler()

        # Set up file handler for logging to file, if required
        self._setFileConfigs()
        self._setFileHandler()
```

To date, my solution does not exploit `setLoggerClass` unfortunately:

```
# Manually create an instance of CustomLogger with extra
# NOTE: use directly CustomLogger class instead of setting it with setLoggerClass
logger = CustomLogger("app", extra=extra)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG) # example to overwrite the init level from extra

# Optionally, if you want this logger to be retrievable via logging.getLogger("app")
# you can manually add it to the logging manager's dictionary
logging.Logger.manager.loggerDict["app"] = logger

logger = logging.getLogger("app")
```

EDIT:

```
# base levels should be accessed within the logging namespace
# e.g. with logging.INFO, logging.DEBUG, etc.
# custom levels should be accessed withing the following Enum class
# e.g. with CustomLogger.CustomLevels.QUERY, CustomLogger.CustomLevels.PROFILE, etc.
class CustomLevels(Enum):
    PROFILE = 19
    QUERY = 21
    EMAIL = 31

def _addCustomLevels(self) -> None:
    # Helper function to create a logging method for a specific log level
    def make_log_method(level: CustomLevels):
        def log_method(self, message, *args, **kwargs):
            # NOTE: optimize by checking level before logging
            # https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#optimization
            if self.isEnabledFor(level.value):
                self._log(level.value, message, args, **kwargs)
        return log_method

    # Register custom log levels and methods
    for level in CustomLevels:
        logging.addLevelName(level.value, level.name)
        setattr(CustomLogger, level.name.lower(), make_log_method(level))
        # optional: add the custom level to the logging namespace as well
        # setattr(logging, level.name, level.value)
```

Comment: Could it be that you are trying to achieve in `Logger` what would typically be done in a class derived from `logging.Handler`? See https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#handler-basic
You might even be able to use the existing handlers, e.g. FileHandler, StreamHandler etc. and simply put your custom logic in a factory method for obtaining the handler.

Comment: @ypnos I have subclassed handlers and formatters and using them in the class methods called in the init. The logger subclass is used to add come custom levels (INFO+1, DEBUG+1, WARNING+1) to add some finer logging tracing customized by my app. The formatters are subclassed to add colored output, I have a custom STMP handler subclass that change the subject dynamically based on the extra parameters (e.g. if my app needs some manual intervention from delevoper in some edge cases, etc.).

Comment: My idea was more along the lines of, having the custom levels etc. as a static part of your class but all the customized `extra` stuff might be well handled by respective handler or filter. But I am not sure how well these things separate for your use-case :-)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are mixing the definition and the configuration of your logging infrastructure. Adding handlers and setting the level of a logger is configuration and doesn't belong into the definition of a custom logger class. The normal approach is to have a separate method or class that configures the logging. A good way to think about it is assuming that your CustomLogger class will be used in a different project and what parts of it are specific to the current project? Those don't belong in the class, those are configuration.

```py
import logging

class CustomLogger(logging.Logger):   
    def __init__(
        self,
        name: str,
        level: int = logging.NOTSET
    ) -> None:
        super().__init__(name, level)
        # whatever else you want to do here. e.g. set up custom log levels

logging.setLoggerClass(CustomLogger)

def setup_logging(name, extra):
    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    debug_mode = extra.get("debug_mode", False)
    level = logging.DEBUG if debug_mode else logging.INFO
    logger.setLevel(level)

    # add handlers and formatters here

    return logger
```

Comment: I edited the question with the code to add the custom levels. In your design pattern I would call that method as shown in your solution in the init. What about the logging setup with the getLogger method? For instance, if I have my main script main() and another other(), would I call getLogger("app") in my main, and getLogger("app.other")?

Comment: Since your customLogger looks so much like a god-class I assumed there would only be one. If you are creating many loggers of this you can split `setup_logging` into `init_logging` that you call once and a `get_logger` that wraps around `getLogger` and handles log-level logic. Stuff like SMTP handlers are usually not added to multiple loggers but only the the root/parent of the logger hierarchy and the rest of the loggers just propagates there. Adding handlers only to the root and having the other loggers just propagate might help you avoid the custom logger class altogether.

Comment: yes, I am designing a "god-class" logger. I can add the configuration as you stated but the custom log levels are mandatory so I think I need a subclass of the logger class, don't I? I would like to explore also the use of "children" loggers by using getLogger properly but I don't know how. Considering the root logger the "app" logger, i would just call `getLogger("app.child")` elsewhere, right? Or something like `getLogger(f"app.{__name__}")`

Comment: I implemented your solution but somehow (not understanding why atm) the console output tracing is replicated twice (one formatted as wanted, the other idk):

For instance:
[DEBUG   2024-02-20 15:22:30]: Logging setup: logging to file is set!
DEBUG:app:Logging setup: logging to file is set!